# WebStorm is adding unwanted line breaks in <p> tag

Tags: ejs, webstorm, reformatting

I have this code in an .ejs file, writing the second block on the web page:

```html
<h1>
    written by "<span class='accent'><%= params.user %></span>"
</h1>
```

```
written by "Salmon"
```

However, when I'm reformatting my code in WebStorm (Ctrl+Alt+L) it will change it to this, resulting in unwanted spaces before and after the quotation marks:

```html
<h1>
    written by "
    <span class='accent'><%= params.user %></span>
    "
</h1>
```

```
written by " Salmon "
```

I've tried going through the HTML & EJS code style pages in WebStorm, removing `h1` from the lists it appears in to no avail. Besides those changes that I later rolled back I am using default settings.

[image: WebStorm]

Comment: what **Hard wrap at** value is specified in **Settings | Editor | Code Style**?

Comment: @lena It's 0 columns, both for the general "Code Style" tab and for the "HTML" sub tab.

Comment: that's the reason. Try changing it to some reasonable value. Note that EJS templates don't use HTML code style settings

Comment: @lena Changing the hard wrap value doesn't seem to have any effect unfortunately. I am 99% sure I am running on default style settings besides that one, is there anything else I might have to change? It's an .ejs file, and I can repro it with only the h1-tag in the first code block.